# Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type DateHandler

Tags: c#, postgresql, function, npgsql

I am working with npg with postgresql

I am facing below error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0TKn.jpg

function

```
-- select public.getmonthfromdatetestO('2022-01-02')
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getmonthfromdatetestO(
    orderdate date)
    --albumid integer)
    RETURNS SETOF record 
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
SELECT count(albumid) ,extract(month FROM orderdate) AS yr_month
    FROM public.orderalbum
    WHERE
        extract(year FROM orderdate) = 2022
        GROUP BY albumid,orderdate  
        --GROUP BY albumid,orderdate
--select extract(month from orderdate)::int;
$BODY$;
```

o/p of function

```
(13,12)
(13,12)
(13,12)
(13,12)
(13,12)
(13,12)
(6,12)
(6,12)
(13,12)
(14,12)
(14,12)
```

HomeController

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getmonthSales()
        {      
            string sql3 = @"getmonthfromdatetestO";
 
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand pgcom = new NpgsqlCommand(sql3, conn);
            pgcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            
            pgcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderdates", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, "2022-01-01");
            
            NpgsqlDataReader pgreader = pgcom.ExecuteReader();

            while (pgreader.Read())
            {
                int albumid = pgreader.GetInt32(1);
                int surname = pgreader.GetInt32(2);
            }
```

stackTrace :

```
   at lambda_method(Closure , NpgsqlTypeHandler , Object , NpgsqlLengthCache& , NpgsqlParameter )
   at Npgsql.TypeHandling.NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler`1.ValidateObjectAndGetLength(Object value, NpgsqlLengthCache& lengthCache, NpgsqlParameter parameter)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ValidateAndGetLength()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ValidateParameters()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__100.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MvcPractical.Controllers.HomeController.getmonthSales() in C:\Users\patilr\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MvcPractical\MvcPractical\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 233
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

I am trying and trying but not work
I am continuously changing the function and also the c# but different error I am getting

I am searching error on google and changes in function and c# side but my issue is not solved that s why I am writing my question here

need help

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a string as a date - create a DateOnly instance from your string (`DateOnly.Parse("2022-01-01")`) and pass that as your parameter value.

Comment: error is ```The name 'DateOnly' does not exist in the current context``` can you help more

Comment: I create a instance but not work please check ```DateTime DateOnly = new DateTime();```

Comment: DateOnly was introduced in .NET 6.0 and supported in Npgsql 6.0, so that should work unless you're on an older version (no longer supported). If DateTime isn't working for you, you'll need to post both your code and your exception ("no working" doesn't help us help you).